# A correct way to implement "fixed" joint?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Am I right that there is no `fixed` joint type in SDF similar to one in URDF? So how should I implement one?

In one of the [tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/build_robot/add_laser) Hokuyo laser is attached to a mobile platform with `revolute` joint, but with zero limits:

```
<joint name="hokuyo_joint" type="revolute">
  <child>hokuyo::link</child>
  <parent>chassis</parent>
  <axis>
    <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
    <limit>
      <upper>0</upper>
      <lower>0</lower>
    </limit>
  </axis>
</joint>
```

Same approach is used in `Simple Arm` model, to attach it to the ground.

Although it seems ok, but there is an extra joint control on `Joints` pane which of course does not control anything. Also there is an extra coordinate frame marker in scene.

So is it the only way to implement fixed joints?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1321/a-correct-way-to-implement-%22fixed%22-joint?/) by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-02-08

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A fixed joint does not exist in simulation. The URDF parser auto-magically eliminates fixed joint by restructuring the URDF contents.

There are two ways to attach two models together:

1. Use a revolute joint with zero limits.
2. Include a model inside another (this is the preferred method because it doesn't introduce an additional constraint on the system). Take a look at `worlds/model_nesting.world` as an example.

There is only one way to attach a model to the world (which means it's fixed at its location of creation), and this is through a joint.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-02-09**:
Thanks for clarification!

**Comment by [Andrew Hundt](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/685/andrew-hundt/) on 2014-03-21**:
model_nesting is in the deprecated folder now, is there another solution to this?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-03-25**:
At the moment only a revolute joint with zero limits between two models is supported.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

For the people finding this question on Google: fixed joints are directly supported in Gazebo since Gazebo6 , using the "fixed" joint type.

---

Originally posted by [silvio.traversaro](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/455/silvio.traversaro/) with karma: 200 on 2015-10-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yah130s](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1228/yah130s/) on 2015-10-21**:
+1 for raising this to attention (although `fixed` doesn't seem to be available on Model Editor 6.4 yet).

**Comment by [Dennis Leroy Wigand](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2423/dennis-leroy-wigand/) on 2016-01-28**:
Thank you very much for pointing that out!

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2016-05-02**:
The model editor (8.0 version) does support inserting fixed joint. I tested it with the gazebo8 nightly.

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2016-05-02**:
The model editor (8.0 version) does support inserting fixed joint. I tested it with the gazebo8 nightly package.